# RoR send email with html template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-email

I would like send email with **html.erb** template and I have some code.
Like this:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def notification(to_email)
    begin
      mail(to: 'test@oooooo.com', subject: "Test message")
      rescue Exception => e
      return
    end
  end
end
```

And some **html.erb** file:

```
Hello, <%= @name %>.
```

But I don't know how to attach this template for my method.
Help me please with this issue, because i can't fount normally manual about it.

Comment: ok, but how to transfer data to html.erb file?

Comment: You can have a view page under `app/views/mailer` with the name `notification.html.erb` with the code, so that it renders the view while calling that method

Comment: @TarasKovalenko you just define instance variable in notification method

Comment: ok, thanks, just now I can't catch exception but I not take email ;( I use ssl. Maybe need some settings for ActionMailer::Base ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a page named `notification.html.erb` in `app/views/mailer` directory. You will get all instance variable in `notification.html.erb` that is defined in your `def notification(to_email)`

```
def notification(to_email)
  @name = #pass name here
  #your code goes here 
end
```

Now `@name` will be available in `notification.html.erb` like

```
Hello, <%= @name %>
```